# What is the mathematical rigorous proof that L1 regularization will give sparse solution?

Tags: machine-learning, regularization

It is given in the book Machine Learning A probabilistic Perspective, but i am not able to understand it. Can some one provide an explanation for that ?

I am not clear with the way sub gradient is defined and how is it helping in the optimization [image] [image].[image]

Comment: The proof, such as it were, is in the pudding.  I.e., a lot of numerical experience.  That is not a rigorous proof that sparseness is always achieved.

Comment: So there is no proof, just practical observations that say sparsity is achieved ?

Comment: I think there is a feeling or hope that L1 might induce sparsity, based on L0 really inducing sparseness and "closeness" of L1 to L0.  And there is a large body of experience that it often (usually) does, at least to some extent.

Comment: When I don't understand the proof I usually conclude that I don't need it

Comment: @MarkL.Stone To be sure that this is clear: the work that statisticians have put into the lasso has been related to understanding *which* model the lasso selects. It is rigorous and quick to show that that the lasso does induce sparsity (consider, for instance, having large tuning parameter as shown here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/210040)

Answer (score 9):

### Answer

As shown in my answer at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/210040/, the lasso estimator $$\hat\beta_\lambda = \arg\min_{\beta \in \mathbb{R}^p} \left\{ \|y - X \beta\|_2^2 + \lambda \|\beta\|_1 \right\}$$ equals zero if and only if $\lambda \geq \frac{1}{n} \|X^T y\|_\infty =: \lambda_\max$. This result does, in some sense, answer your question: we now know that for a large enough tuning parameter $\lambda$, the lasso estimator $\hat\beta_\lambda$ is fully sparse. On the other hand, we also know that there exists a least squares estimator $\hat\beta_0$ which is almost surely fully dense.

### More

*assumption:* For convenience, let us assume that every estimator considered is unique. (If the estimators are not unique, all we've shown is that there exists *at least one* estimator that is sparse, which also answers the question.)

> In light of this, we may be interested in knowing more about the possible sizes of the support of $\hat\beta_\lambda$ for $\lambda \in (0, \lambda_\max)$. In particular, we'll now answer whether it's true that for all $k \in \{0, 1, \dots, p\}$, there exists $\lambda$ so that $\mathrm{card} (\mathrm{supp} (\hat\beta_\lambda)) = k$. It turns out that the answer is (almost surely) yes! The best proof I can come up with relies on explicitly constructing the lasso solution. (If there's a better proof you know, please do comment!)

Since we've answered the other cases above, restrict $k \in (1, \dots, p-1)$.  Write the knots of the lasso solution path as $0 \leq \lambda_1 \leq \dots \leq \lambda_q$. Let $\lambda_{r+1}$ be the largest knot so that $\mathrm{card}(\mathrm{supp}(\hat\beta_\lambda)) \leq k$ for all $\lambda > \lambda_{r+1}$. By definition, we know that a feature will leave the support at the knot $\lambda_{r+1}$. We will know show that *exactly* one will leave the support.

From KKT considerations ([to be filled in later](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~larry/=sml/sparsity.pdf#page=9)), we see that, for $\lambda \in [\lambda_r, \lambda_{r+1}]$, $$\hat\beta_\lambda^j = \hat\beta_{\lambda_r}^j + (\lambda_r - \lambda) e_j^T (X_S^T X_S)^{-1} z_S$$ for $j \in S$, and $\hat\beta_\lambda^j = 0$ for $j \not\in S$. Here $S = \mathrm{supp} (\hat\beta_{\lambda_r})$ and $z$ is the subgradient of the $\ell_1$ norm evaluated at $\hat\beta_{\lambda_r}$. Assuming that $j$ is one of the features that leaves the active set at the knot $\lambda_{r+1}$, we can set the above equation to zero and solve for $\lambda$ to find that $$\lambda_{r+1} = \lambda_r + \frac{\hat\beta_j^{\lambda_r}}{e_j^T (X_S^T X_S)^{-1} z_S}.$$ (Note that if the denominator were zero, then the $j^\textrm{th}$ feature could not be leaving the active set at the knot $\lambda_{r+1}$.) At this point, we see that the proof will conclude when it is shown that $$\lambda_j^\mathrm{update} := \frac{\hat\beta_j^{\lambda_r}}{e_j^T (X_S^T X_S)^{-1} z_S}$$ is distinct for each $j \in S$. However, the subgradient $z_S \in \{-1,1\}^{|S|}$, a finite set, and so it follows that under a continuous distribution on the response $y$, the update $\lambda_j^\mathrm{update}$ is almost surely unique for each $j \in S$.