# LASSO: Deriving the smallest lambda at which all coefficient are zero

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, lasso

I'am trying to derive mathematically the lowest $\lambda$ at which all coefficients are zero, referring to the Exercise 2.1 of the book [Sparsity with Statistical Learning](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ehastie/StatLearnSparsity_files/SLS_corrected_1.4.16.pdf).
The result should be $\lambda_{min}=\max_j |X_j^Ty|$. I hope this isn't a duplicate, because it is also discussed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/210040/lasso-and-ridge-tuning-parameter-scope/283049#283049). However my math skills are very restricted, so I don't understand the solution. I hope that someone can help me to understand the mathematical details behind the derivation.
The LASSO is defined as:

$\min_\beta \frac{1}{2}\Vert y-X\beta\Vert_2^2 +\lambda\Vert\beta\Vert_1$

My approach was following the KKT-conditions, we get

$X^T (y-X\hat{\beta})=\lambda s$

with $s$ as the subgradient.
$\beta=0$ leads to

$X^Ty=\lambda s \Leftrightarrow \frac{X^Ty}{s}=\lambda$

And here I'm stuck. How I can get from there to this $\lambda_{min}=\max_j |X_j^Ty| $

**EDIT**: The Exercise question of the book is:
"Show that the smallest value of  such that the regression coefficients
estimated by the lasso are all equal to zero is given by"

$\lambda_{max}=|\frac{1}{N}\langle x_j,y\rangle|$

**EDIT2:** Source of the KKT-[image]Condition

Comment: It looks to me like you've derived the solution for when there is a singe variable in the model (with a single coefficient $\beta$). How would this generalize to a case with multiple variables, where all the coefficients need to be 0? What $\lambda$ would you need then?

Comment: This should be the solution where all coefficients are zeor. My last equation is in Matrix/vector form, so $\beta$ is a vector. The result, stated and the end is from the texbook. I updated my post, regarding the exercise

Comment: You're not too far from the derivation you linked to. Just remember that $s$ is a vector so you can't just divide $X^Ty$ by $s$. Look over the other answer again, noting $\hat{z}_{\lambda,j}$ is the subgradient and the infinity norm is the maximum absolute value of the elements of a vector.

Comment: Why I can apply there the infinity norm on both sides? I've read first time there about this norm (my math skills are very horrible). Thats the step: "$\frac{1}{n} \|X^T y \|_\infty = \lambda \|\hat{z}_{\lambda}\|_\infty.$" I dont get. Is the infinity norm just like an operator, that I can apply on both sides ?

Comment: The KKT conditions are tricky when $\Vert \beta \Vert_1$ has no well defined gradient everywhere. I don' know your expression so well but are you sure you should not have something like the subgradient on both sides of the equation?

Comment: In this question you may find a lot of intuition https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/289075/what-is-the-smallest-lambda-that-gives-a-0-component-in-lasso/291367

Comment: Already read that, but I couldnt continue in my mathematical derivation

Comment: @rook1996 can you give a reference where you obtained the condition using subgradients. I believe there must be some mistake there. There is not a single *'the subgradient'* as any vector is a subgradient for $\Vert \beta \Vert_1$ when $\beta = 0$. So you will have to maximize over all the different possible subgradients. Also you will probably have to take something like the *directional derivative* (along the direction of the 'chosen' subgradient) for the first term instead of the gradient. If you apply this you should be able to continue working it out.

Comment: Look at my edit. That are notes from lecture slide of Tibshirani in Stanford. Also look at the other forum post. They did the same

Comment: I do not know the KKT conditions for non differentiable functions but the equation (9) that you quote does not seem right, it is probably a typo or something like that. The left hand side is the gradient of $\frac{1}{2}||y-X\beta||_2^2$ but it should be the directional derivative ($\nabla_\vec{s}$) instead.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the question is not so much a duplicate and a useful addition. The issue of finding the smallest $\lambda$ for which all coefficients are zero has occurred before on this website but not explicitly as a question (which make this question an useful reference point).

- **The opposite of your question:** Deriving the largest lambda at which all coefficients are non-zero [What is the smallest $\lambda$ that gives a 0 component in lasso?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/289075)
- **Your question for a slightly different case (grouped lasso):** [How is the minimum $\lambda$ computed in group LASSO?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/340486)
- **Your question answered in a different but related question:** optimizing computation with a grid search by choosing a useful range of $\lambda$ [Lasso and Ridge tuning parameter scope](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/210040) (this is the one that you reference yourselve in your question)

---

#### Something is wrong with your formulation using the KKT conditions

I do not know the Karush–Kuhn–Tucker (KKT) conditions for non differentiable functions but the equation (9), $X^T(y-X\hat\beta) = \lambda s$, that you quote does not seem right, it is probably a typo or something like that. The left hand side is the gradient of $\frac{1}{2}||y-X\beta||_2^2$ but it should be the directional derivative ($\nabla_\vec{s}$) instead (or something related).

**If we explain it in other words (not using the KKT conditions)** then you can see it as following

- For finding a (local) minimum of the function below

  $$\mathcal{L}(\beta) =  \frac{1}{2}||y-X\beta||_2^2 +\lambda||\beta||_1 $$

  you should have in *all* directions $\vec{s}$ the following condition

  $$\nabla_{\vec{s}} \mathcal{L}(\beta) \geq 0 $$

  in words: for a local maximum there is no direction $\vec{s}$ along which you can change $\beta$ to make the objective function $\mathcal{L}(\beta)$ decrease.

  (This is slightly different than the typical derivative being *equal* to zero. We use an inequality instead of equality to zero because the function is not smooth).

  This changes the question into finding the $\lambda$ for which

  $$\max_\vec{s} \left[ \nabla_{\vec{s}} \mathcal{L}(0) \right] = 0 $$

  or (when $\beta = 0 $)

  $$\max_\vec{s} \left[  \left(X^Ty\right) \cdot \vec{s} - \lambda \Vert \vec{s} \Vert_1\right] = 0$$

  after some shifting of terms

  $$\max_\vec{s} \left[  \left(X^Ty\right) \cdot \frac{\vec{s}}{\Vert \vec{s} \Vert_1} \right] = \lambda$$

---

#### An intuitive geometrical interpretation with LARS regression

*To explain the problem more intuitively we are going to use a geometrical interpretation of the algorithm for LARS (least angle regression. LARS gives, at least, for $\beta$ sufficiently close to zero gives the same set of solutions as LASSO)*

*With LARS solutions for the optimization problem are found as a function of $\lambda$. These solutions are found by following a path along which the residual sum of squares term decreases the most for a given change in the norm term $\beta$.*

Define $\lambda_{max}$ such that for $\lambda < \lambda_{max}$ we have at least *one* non-zero coefficient, and for $\lambda  \geq \lambda_{max}$ we have all coefficients zero).

**For $\lambda>\lambda_{max}$** we have $\hat{\beta}^\lambda$ = 0. The penalty in the term $\lambda \vert \vert \beta \vert \vert_1$ will be too large, and an increase/change of $\beta$ (imagine gradient descent to find an optimum) does not reduce $\frac{1}{2} \Vert y-X \beta \Vert ^2_2$ sufficiently to get a reduction in $\frac{1}{2} \vert \vert y-X \beta \vert \vert ^2_2 + \lambda \vert \vert \beta \vert \vert_1$

**For $\lambda=\lambda_{max}$** The basic idea is that we can decrease $\lambda$ untill some point where a change of $\beta$ is possible such that an increase of $\vert \vert \beta \vert \vert_1$ will cause the term $(1/2) \vert \vert y-X \beta \vert \vert ^2_2$ to decreases more than the term $\lambda \vert \vert \beta \vert \vert_1$ increases. To find this $\lambda_{max}$:

- Determine the angle, or unit vector $\beta_0$, along which the sum $(y - X\beta)^2$ would decrease most (for given change of $\Vert \beta \Vert_0$). (in the same way as the first step in the LARS algorithm explained in the very nice article from professor Efron and others,  http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/LARS/LeastAngle_2002.pdf) This would relate to the variable(s) $x_i$ that correlates the most with $y$.
- Calculate the rate of change at which the sum of squares of the error change if you increase the length of the predicted vector $\hat{y}$

  $r_1= \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial\sum{(y - X\beta_0\cdot s)^2}}{\partial s}$

  this is related to the angle between $\vec{\beta_0}$ and $\vec{y}$. The change of the square of the length of the error term $y_{err}$ will be equal to

  $$\frac{\partial y_{err}^2}{\partial \vert \vert \beta_0 \vert \vert _1} = 2 y_{err} \frac{\partial y_{err}}{\partial \vert \vert \beta_0 \vert \vert _1} = 2 \vert \vert y \vert \vert _2 \vert \vert X\beta_0 \vert \vert _2 cor(\beta_0,y)$$

  The term $\vert \vert X\beta_0 \vert \vert _2 cor(\beta_0,y)$ is how much the length $y_{err}$ changes as the coefficient $\beta_0$ changes.
- Then $\lambda_{max}$ is equal to this rate of change and $\lambda_{max} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial\sum{(y - X\beta_0\cdot s)^2}}{\partial s} = \frac{1}{2} 2 \vert \vert y \vert \vert _2 \vert \vert x \vert \vert _2 corr(\beta_0,y) = \vert \vert X\beta_0 \cdot y \vert \vert _2 $

  Where $\beta_0$ is the unit vector that corresponds to the angle in the first step of the LARS algorithm.

If $k$ is the number of vectors that share the maximum correlation then we have

$\lambda_{max} = \sqrt{k} \vert \vert X^T y\vert \vert_\infty  $

**In other words. LARS gives you the initial decrease of the SSE-term (sum of squared error) as you increase the length of the vector $\beta$ (the penalty term) and the ratio of these is then equal to your $\lambda_{max}$**

The image below explains the concept how the LARS algorithm can help in finding $\lambda_{max}$.

- In the image we see schematically the fitting of the vector $y$ by the vectors $x_1$ and $x_2$.
- The dotted gray vectors depict the OLS (ordinary least squares) solution with $y_{\perp}$ the
  part of $y$ that is perpendicular (the error) to the span of the vectors $x_1$
  and $x_2$ *(and the perpendicular vector is the shortest distance and
  the smallest sum of squares)*
- the gray lines are iso-lines for which $\vert \vert \beta \vert \vert_1$ is constant
- The vectors $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ depict the path that is being followed in a LARS regression.
- The blue lines and green lines are the vectors that depict the error term, which decreases when the penalty term decreases and the solution 'moves' along the LARS path from $0$ to $\hat{\beta}_{OLS}$.

  The length of these lines corresponds to the SSE and when they reach the
  perpendicular vector $y_{\perp}$ you have the least sum of squares

Now, initially the path is followed along the vector $x_i$ that has the highest correlation with $y$. For this vector the change of the $\sqrt{SSE}$ as function of the change of $\vert \vert \beta \vert \vert$ is largest (namely equal to the correlation of that vector $x_i$ and $y$). While you follow the path this change of $\sqrt{SSE}$/$\vert \vert \beta \vert \vert$ decreases until a path along a combination of two vectors becomes more 'efficient', and so on. Notice that the ratio of the change $\sqrt{SSE}$ and change $\vert \vert \beta \vert \vert$ is a monotonously decreasing function. Therefore, the solution for $\lambda_{max}$ must be at the origin.

[image: graphical example of LARS procedure]